# Python function, returning False and None

Tags: python, return

I have this function

```
def postData():
    data = doPOst()
    if data.result == "success":
       return data
    if data.result == "fail":
       return false
```

Then i based on return i have to do something like

```
if ret is None:
   pass # 1
if ret is False:
   pass # 2
else:
   normal
```

I want to know that will None and False get mixed

Comment: Do you mean `return false` or `return False`? Also -- how can `data` be None? It seems like you either return something or return False

Comment: @JohnColeman None will be rturned if for some reaosn postcall timeout and there is no data there

Comment: @JohnKaff if doPost() returns None, then the ifs will fail with AttributeErrors (since None will not have a result attribute)

Comment: @Sebastian My thought exactly -- `data` is being *used* -- it can't be None

Comment: @JohnColeman i will be using .d.get() so that i don't get error . but it may also happen that result is something other than success or fail .Won't happen but in some cases

Answer (score 3):

If you check for `None` and `False` explicitly, then no, they will not get combined.

```
if ret is None: # entered only on None
    pass
elif ret == False: # entered only on False or 0
    pass
else:
    pass
```

If you just checked for truthy/falsey values, they would get combined:

```
if ret:
    pass
else: # entered on None or False
    pass
```

Comment: Whats difference using if but not elif .

Comment: @JohnKaff if you are returning in each if, then the overall behavior will be the same. However, IMHO it's better style to use elifs since they describe the reasoning in the code more closely (i.e. the fact that they are mutually exclusive outcomes)

Comment: John, I wanted to clarify that the if vs. elif is irrelevant to your original question. Notice how Tigerhawk's first example is explicitly checking whether ret is None, or False, or something else. In his second example, None, False, and 0 would all be considered the same.